# Connect to AWS RDS mssql using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, rds

I'm developing an app that requires a database and I'm attempting to use Amazon Web Service RDS and I have the security set to accept any IP from and port and I'm able to access the database using Microsoft SQL Server Manager, but when I attempt to connect using a test program in C#, I'm not able to establish a connection. I'm not getting a rejected connection, but a connection that can't even find the server. Am I going at this wrong? Here's my test code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public static class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetConnection();
}

public static void GetConnection()
{
    string ConnectionFormat = "Server={0}; Database={1}; Uid=tie; Pwd=dune";
    string Database = "juniorproject";
    string Server = @"copy pasta,1433";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(string.Format(ConnectionFormat, Database, Server)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(connection.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: By default RDS will not allow connections. You have to add your client IP in rds to allow connections from that IP.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? If yes, would you please share?

Answer (score 0):

Your server name doesn't even look close to right - it is going to be a much longer string, i.e. something like this:

```
myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

you'll need to lookup the actual endpoint in the AWS console.

Comment: That's why I typed in copy pasta. I know my endpoint server name but I didn't want to broadcast it to the world when I posted this question so I changed the server, username, and password. I know those three pieces of data are correct because I can connect to SSMS with the information I have.